# Python Pandas Count Number of DataFrame Columns in which a Particular Value Occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
              A       B       C

1/2/2007    np.Nan   6.3     np.Nan
1/3/2007    np.Nan   np.Nan   3.2
1/4/2007    np.Nan   np.Nan   np.Nan
1/5/2007     -999    np.Nan   7.3
1/6/2007    np.Nan    -999    np.Nan
1/7/2007    np.Nan   np.Nan   3.1
1/8/2007    np.Nan    -999    np.Nan
```

How can I get a count of columns with the value -999?

Not the number of occurrences in the dataframe or the number of occurrances per column but the number of the columns with the value?

The correct answer here would be `2` since columns A and B have at least one occurance of `-999` which column C has `0` occurrances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first compare your entire df with -999, then count the number of none zero columns.

```
df.eq(-999).any().sum()
Out[302]: 2
```

A bit explanation:

df.eq(-999) gives a True/False matrix, indicating if the element is equal to -999:

```
Out[308]: 
              A      B      C
1/2/2007  False  False  False
1/3/2007  False  False  False
1/4/2007  False  False  False
1/5/2007   True  False  False
1/6/2007  False   True  False
1/7/2007  False  False  False
1/8/2007  False   True  False
```

.any() checks if any element in a column is True, which returns:

```
Out[309]: 
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

In this example, Column A and B are true since they have at least one Trues.

Finally, .sum() counts the number of Trues, (True is automatically cast to 1 and False to 0 in a sum operation)

Comment: aha, Nice modify :-)

Comment: Interesting - and thanks.  Could you explain the syntax a bit. It isn't intuitive to me.  How does the syntax 'know' we are talking about columns in this case instead of rows?